# iOS UIWebView not showing keyboard when textfields receive focus

Tags: ios, uiwebview, keyboard

I have a UIWebView embeded as a subview which loads an html form from the web. The problem is that when you select one of the text fields it receives the focus, but the keyboard does not display. this only happens on iOS6 if i run this app on iOS 4.3, 5.1 etc it works as expected. Any one have any advice

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[webView setKeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction:YES];

// load url here
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:redirectUrl];
//URL Requst Object
NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[requestObj setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
UIScrollView* sv = nil;
for(UIView* v in [webView subviews]){
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class] ]){
        sv = (UIScrollView*) v;
        sv.scrollEnabled = NO;
        sv.bounces = NO;

    }
}
[webView setOpaque:NO];
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
webView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:webView];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the answer of this question:

[Some UITextfields don't respond in iOs6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585463/some-uitextfields-dont-respond-in-ios6)

You have to resingfirstresponder **before** presentmodalviewcontroller in the the controller where are you calling the view with the problem.

BUT, you also have to resignfirst responder in all previews controllers, that is.

In my case i go from a searchbar to a detail view, and from detail to share in facebook. The view of share in facebook wasn't showing the keyboard, and it was 'cause i wasn't resiginif first responder of search bar.

Hope it helps.